# Set edittext aligment only for new input, not for the entire text

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/scriptNameTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />
```

**I have such an edittext and the following java code:**

```
if(position == 1) {
      editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      editText.append("\n");
} else  {
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    editText.append("\n");
}
```

When position equals 1, all text is centered, else all text is aligned to the left. But I need to align only new text (exculding the previously entered text and targeting only newly entered chars), not all text in edittext. How can I do it?

Comment: The term new text means you are exculding the previously entered text and targetting only newly entered chars ?

Comment: Yes, that means exactly what you said)

Comment: And how has that previous text gotten there? Entered, or pre-filled, or what?

Comment: All text in edittext is entered by user.